# loading external web service in PhoneGap/Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I've been trying to load an external web service in my Sencha Touch 2 app (which will be built with PhoneGap Build) but I can't seem to get it working. I'm using the [W3Schools example web service](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp) as a test. I've read that PhoneGap can do this because it uses the `file:///` protocol, but I've had no luck loading a web service.

Here is the `Ext.Ajax.request` call I am making:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit',
    method: 'POST',
    xmlData: {
        Celsius: "25.0"
    },

    success: function(response) {
        container.setHtml(container.getHtml() + '<br/>Ext.Ajax.request succeeded');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        container.setHtml(container.getHtml() + '<br/>Ext.Ajax.request failed');
    }
});
```

I always seem to get the failed message though. In my `config.xml`, I do have the access tag:

```
<access origin = "*" subdomains="true"/>
```

And I built with PhoneGap build using PhoneGap 2.0.0 as the PhoneGap version, tested on my Android phone with version 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using phonegap, you need to allow the cross-domain requests from phonegap. This worked with jQuery-Mobile and PhoneGap but should be the same for Sencha-Touch.

Also have you given the permissions to access the internet in the manifest file.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164136/load-jquery-mobile-page-from-different-domain/12171043#12171043)