# Load jQuery Mobile page from different domain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to load a jQuery AJAX Enabled page from a external page? I'm making an app with phonegap and I need one page to be hosted online because it is going to be continually updated, but I cant seem to figure out how! I tried just linking it, but that didn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is it's because cross domain ajax isn't allowed. Could you set `data-ajax="false"` (or whatever it's called) and load the page "like normal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with PhoneGap you can set up a whitelist to work around the Cross-Origin-Policy. You have to maintain this whitelist specifically for each of your target platforms.

Check out this Guide (PhoneGap 1.9+):
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

If you are on an older version of PhoneGap you have to pay attention to some inconsistencies regarding the white-list entry syntax amongst different platforms.

If you are using jQueryMobile, also check out this PhoneGap specific advices:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery-mobile?

Anyways you can always use the following configuration to allow cross domain requests through ajax. You can also refer to the documentation link given below that would help you better understand.

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
});
```

You can also use the JSONP plugin for phonegap if the above method does not work for you. Here is a sample.

[JSONP Example](http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/)

[jQuery-Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html)